# What is the maximum size for an image source?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am trying to draw of a JPEG image of 2189 by 4996 pixels in Mapbox GL JS, but it's rendering black, with the following exception:

> WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: width or height out of range

Is there a maximum dimension that is not documented? Or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok. It seems that the MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 4096, so I will need to make sure that the image is smaller than that.